# mysql2 gem install fails with unmet dependencies: libmysqlclient-dev

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, mariadb

I am experiencing a similar issue to [this poster on the askubuntu forums](https://askubuntu.com/questions/667543/how-do-you-fix-unmet-dependencies-but-something-is-to-be-installed-error). I've started with a clean Ubuntu 14.04 install several times now and keep getting the same error no matter [what I do](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17932972/installing-mariadb-unmet-dependencies-mariadb-server-10-0).

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libmysqlclient-dev : Depends: libmysqlclient18 (= 5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2) but 10.0.23+maria-1~trusty is to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Reproducing the error:

1. Followed the instructions on the [MariaDB site](https://downloads.mariadb.org/mariadb/repositories/#mirror=digitalocean-nyc&distro=Ubuntu&distro_release=trusty--ubuntu_trusty&version=10.0) for version 10.0. I tried 10.1 as well in a previous attempt.
2. I have Ruby (2.2.3) on Rails (4.2.5) installed on my server. Setup my app, configure the `Gemfile` and `bundle install`

   ```
   An error occurred while installing mysql2 (0.4.2), and Bundler cannot continue.
       Make sure that `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.2'` succeeds before bundling.
   ```
3. Then I `gem install mysql2 -v '0.4.2'` and get the following:

   ```
   mysql client is missing. You may need to 'apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev' or 'yum install mysql-devel', and try again.
   ```
4. So I `apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` and get the error `Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages` as seen in the first part of this post.

Infos:

```
apt-cache policy libmysqlclient18 & 

 libmysqlclient18:
  Installed: 10.0.23+maria-1~trusty
  Candidate: 10.0.23+maria-1~trusty
  Version table:
 *** 10.0.23+maria-1~trusty 0
        500 http://sfo1.mirrors.digitalocean.com/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     5.5.46-0ubuntu0.14.04.2 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     5.5.35+dfsg-1ubuntu1 0
        500 http://mirrors.digitalocean.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

What step am I missing that will get the bundle install to not encounter issues with the mysql2 gem (and still use MariaDB)? `mysql -uroot -p` works okay from the terminal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`purge` all mysql related packages

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
sudo apt-get update
```

Now, that you have a clean system. Try installing mariadb again

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server libmariadbclient-dev mariadb-client mysql-common  libmysqlclient18 libmariadbd-dev
```

just ensure that package version you are being promted to install are the same as given on this page:
http://ftp.yz.yamagata-u.ac.jp/pub/dbms/mariadb/repo/10.0/ubuntu/pool/main/m/mariadb-10.0/

Otherwise, it will install Mysql packages from Ubuntu's official repo which will cause the conflict.If that happens, you should set maria db repo with higher priority as given on this page:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/293619/assign-higher-priority-to-ppa

Hope it helps

Comment: I was indeed missing one of the libraries at the install. Thanks again.